# OpenOffice Calc import special characters in CSV incorrrectly?

Tags: csv, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to import a CSV file to `OpenOffice Calc`, but the program is reading special characters incorrectly.

For example, one of the fields in the CSV is "Puma La Cerámica", but `Calc` imports it incorrectly. The same thing with another string "Puma Titán". `Calc` also reads it inccorrectly.

Here's the printscreen of the OpenOffice Calc Text Import:

[image]

I've been testing with the different formats in the dropdown "Character Set", but it remains the same. I changed the "Language" dropdown to "Spanish", but nothing. The csv file is in Spanish.

Any help is appreciated. For what it's worth, Excel reads it correctly.

Comment: Can we assume that any solution needs to be at your end (you have no control over how the CSV file is prepared)?  The best solution would obviously be interpreting the data correctly on import.  I haven't researched that, but I can think of a workaround until a solution is presented.  There is only a limited number of these special characters, and Calc makes substitutions that are easy to identify.  Worst case, you could apply a collection of SUBSTITUTE expressions to replace any such instances.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have no control over how the csv file is generated.

Comment: Please share the file here. Not with copy and paste, but putting it online and sharing here the URL. There is some encoding problem

Comment: @aborruso, the file belongs to my employer, so I cannot copy it to a public site.

Comment: Excel reads it correctly, so I don't think it's an encoding problem.

Comment: Ok @rbhat I cannot help you. At 99% is an encoding problem

Comment: How come Excel reads it without issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and changing the character set to UTF-8 solved it.

(I would have written this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.)